# Junit testing for the following code

Tags: java, junit

```
public DownloadModelData downloadFiles(
            @RequestParam(value = "modelId", required = true) final ModelId modelId,
            @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) final String type,
            @RequestParam(value = "osId", required = false) final String osId,
            @RequestParam(value = "language", required = false) final String language,
            @RequestParam(value = "subType", required = false) final String subType,
            @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 2000) final Pageable pageable) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(String.format("    -> pageable: %s", pageable));
        }
```

I need to write the junit testing. i have return junit testing for a class and enum. but here i need to check whether it true or false

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Please rephrase.

Comment: I need to write Junit testing for following code

Comment: That code does nothing other than writing a log message and that is something that you normally don't test in a unit test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with every aspect of testing you should ask the question: *What am I trying to test here?*

In this case there is hardly anything worth testing, as you would be checking the correctness of logging which (unless some detailed logging in certain format is part of non-functional requirements for your application) shouldn't be tested. Such detailed testing approach would greatly increase not only development, but also maintenance effort of any application for a very little benefit, instead try to focus on the business logic.

However should you still wish to test your code, you can use one of the mocking frameworks (i.e. Mockito) to inject the mock `logger` and verify (i.e. by calling `Mockito.verify(...)`) whether method with the expected parameters have been called.

Also, on the side note the pre-check `if (logger.isDebugEnabled())` is not required in most cases as as `logger.debug` will check for the logging level anyway. The only situation where it should be used is when the creation of the logged string is expensive (long statement, with multiple concatenations etc.)